# Package balance warning in acmart

Tags: acm, acmart

I'm using the ACM template provided [here](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template). However, I get the following warning both in Overleaf and VSCode (MiKTeX):

> Package balance Warning: You have called \balance in second column Columns might not be balanced.

Can someone tell me how I can remove this warning?

My tex-file:

```
\documentclass[nonacm, sigconf]{acmart}
\settopmatter{printacmref=false}
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{}
\settopmatter{printfolios=true}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Title}
\author{Zarif}
\email{mail@mail.com}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{University of Stackexchange}
  \city{New York}
  \country{US}
}
\date{August 2019}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This is an abstract.
\end{abstract}

\keywords{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Justo nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin. Condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor id. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Fermentum iaculis eu non diam. Faucibus purus in massa tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium. Porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin. Ipsum a arcu cursus vitae. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper. Cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit. Ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla. Porta lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam.

Cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis. Pellentesque elit eget gravida cum. Morbi leo urna molestie at elementum eu. Aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam. Mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris. Tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget. Quam nulla porttitor massa id. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse. Augue neque gravida in fermentum. Condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor. Potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare.

Justo donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra. Felis eget velit aliquet sagittis. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor. Id nibh tortor id aliquet. Sit amet est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet. Risus feugiat in ante metus dictum at tempor commodo. Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id. Praesent tristique magna sit amet purus. Auctor urna nunc id cursus metus. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. Porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id eu. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna. Eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat. Turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed. Enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam in.

Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique. Est sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci. Quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci. Sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique. Semper quis lectus nulla at. Nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis. Massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa. Duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices eros in cursus. Ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac.

Sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst. Mus mauris vitae ultricies leo. Arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit. Et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat. Bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat. Vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis. Faucibus purus in massa tempor nec. Eu nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec. Integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi. Risus quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum. Faucibus purus in massa tempor nec feugiat. Vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus. In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis. Morbi leo urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis. Vitae et leo duis ut. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat. Pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur.

\begin{itemize}
\item item1
\item item2
\item item3
\end{itemize}

\section{Section2}

\section{Section3}    

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As a general guideline, warnings can be ignored if the behavior that is warned about (1) does not actually happen or (2) it does happen but you are not bothered by it, i.e., the result still looks acceptable to you. So in this case the question is: are the columns on the last page actually unbalanced? If yes, do you think this is a problem? If again yes (i.e., the columns are unbalanced and you think this is a problem) then you can try to issue a `\balance` command manually a bit earlier, for example just before the bibliography or edited into the `.bbl` file.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bug in the `acmart` document class. You should manually add the macro `\balance` (no arguments) somewhere in the **first** column of the last page of text.

Comment: This solved my problem. You really need to put the `\balance` macro on the **first** column of the last page. Otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: Doing that breaks the layout completely for me. Now all the text is _only_ in the first column, and the second column is empty.

Comment: Yes, I've the same problem now. @Turion have you a solution?

Comment: @ClaudioPomo I think the very last resort could be to edit the `.bbl` file after it was generated. But before that one should probably try to approach the publishers of your conference/journal, and the maintainers of `acmart` first.

Comment: Inserting `\balance` in the `.bbl` file between the two only (partial) paragraphs on the first column of the last page did not make any visual difference for me.

Answer (score 4):

`\balance` does not currently work for `acmart` template for ACM papers. So what I did to make it work is to copy the entire compiled `.bbl` file to the end of your LaTeX file and remove `\bibliography{xxx.bib}` where `xxx` is the name of your `bib` file. Then add `\vfill\eject` after the reference which makes your final page almost break in half.

Comment: This makes the height of both columns of the last page inconsistent, right?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to remove the warning is to pass `balance=false` to the `acmart` document class:

```latex
\documentclass[balance=false]{acmart}
```

It disables balancing columns in the last page, which doesn't work anyway if you don't manually add `\balance` in the first column of the last page.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks

Comment: This will NOT bypass the checks run by ACM against your submission.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. add multicol:

\usepackage{multicol}

2. wrap bibliography:

**\onecolumn**

**\begin{multicols}{2}**

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}

\bibliography{bibliography}

**\end{multicols}**

Comment: Nice try, but it makes the previous page unbalanced.

Comment: This will insert a page break prior to your bibliography.