# How to balance references in new acmart.cls format?

Tags: bibtex, acmart

I'm trying to balance the last page of my paper. It contains only references formatted with the new `acmart.cls` format, and takes up about 1/4 of the left column. I've already tried a few methods:

```
    \usepackage{balance} 
    \balance
```

and

```
\usepackage{flushend}
```

and

```
    \usepackage{multicol} 
    \begin{multicols}{x}
```

None of these are working. The first two produce no change, and the last one completely destroys the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The `balance` and `flushend` packages do not work on the new ACM format. For ACM format, you can try this below with the `multicol` package:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
%...
%...
%...
\onecolumn
\begin{multicols}{2}
   \bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
   \bibliography{your_bib_file_name}
\end{multicols}
```

Just wrap your bib command lines. Then your reference would be balanced.

Comment: This creates a page break before the bibliography, which is often not desired.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a quick and dirty fix:

Insert a `\newpage` in your `.bbl` to split the last part of your references in two columns....

Comment: So annoying! There are even multiple questions with the same or a similar answer on different StackExchange instances, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149854/how-to-manually-equalize-columns-in-an-ieee-paper-if-using-bibtex#answer-2150991 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/605952/46291